# Prove that: For all sets $A$ and $B$, $A\cap B = A \cup B\Leftrightarrow A = B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I wasn't able to prove this statement. I'd much appreciate if you could lend a helping hand.

Comment: Every element in either of the sets is in both of the sets.

Comment: Prove that every element in A is in B and every element in B is in A.

Comment: Did you draw a Venn Diagram?  Something *really* obvious should hit you on the head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prove the contrapositive.  Assume $A\ne B$.

Then without loss of generality there is $x\in A$ such that $x\not\in B$.

(If not, switch $A$ and $B$.)

Then $x\in A\cup B$ but $x\not\in A\cap B$.

---

Addendum in response to comment where OP asked for direct proof:

If $A=B$, then $A\cup B=A\cup A=A=A\cap A=A\cap B$.

Conversely, if $A\cup B=A\cap B$, then $x\in A\cup B\iff x\in A\cap B$,

so $x\in A $ or $x\in B\iff x\in A $ and $x\in B$,

so $x\in A\implies x\in A $ or $x\in B \implies x\in A $ and $ x\in B\implies x\in B$,

and likewise $x\in B\implies x\in A$, so $A=B$.

Comment: If it's not bother would you please provide me with a direct proof? I've been trying to do it that way and I've not been able. :C

Comment: "If it's not bother would you please provide me with a direct proof"  Just consider which elements are and are not in each set and show the elements in $A$ are the exact same elements of $B$.  Use the fact that if an element is in either $A$ or $B$ it must be in both of them.

Answer (score 2):

We know that
$$A\cap B\subset A \subset A\cup B$$
and
$$A\cap B\subset B\subset A\cup B$$
So,

$$A\cup B =A\cap B \implies $$
$$A\cup B=A\cap B = A =B$$

Now,
$$A=B \implies A\cup B=A=A\cap B$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $A\cup B=(A\cap B)\cup(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$, with all the components on the RHS disjoint.

So if $A\cap B=A\cup B$, then $A\setminus B=\emptyset$ and $B\setminus A=\emptyset$.

But $A\setminus B=\emptyset\iff A\subseteq B$.

Therefore we have  $A\subseteq B, B\subseteq A$, therefore $A=B$.